# npm install -g *no arguments*

Tags: npm, npm-install

What does the command *npm install -g* (no arguments) do? I opened npm docs but didn't get it:

> > In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it installs the current package context (ie, the current working directory) as a global package.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it means is that whatever project currently in, `npm` will take the dependencies from the `package.json`  in your current project folder and then install those dependencies globally.

Comment: Thanks! That means that I run this command by mistake yesterday and I messed up my system :) Now I wonder how to revert...

Comment: Not a problem. I don't know the exact location but you will find a node_modules folder somewhere in your c drive so delete those dependencies from there